# coinmarketcap API Jquery and JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

the code below seems not to be working. Anyone has a bright idea for me. I get no error messages

```
function doIt() {
        $.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?callback=?", {format:"json"}, function(data) {
            dataCoins = data;
        });
    };


    doIt();
```

Comment: Have you verified that the remote server support JSONP? If I open `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?callback=abc`, the result is pure JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: Not all api's support CORS or jsonp in which case you need to use a proxy either on your server or third part service if neither is supported

Comment: I get this error if I try only JSON - > XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That error is very easy to search on web. You need to use a proxy